# Page construction surface with javascript

Tags: javascript, jquery, plugins, content-management-system, designer

I have been using several CMS systems that allow admin to design a web page in an interactive manner by placing columns and blocks onto a page surface.

I want to implement the same design feature on my CMS. Is there a JavaScript libraries (perhaps jQuery or even knockoutJS-enabled) that allow to implement such "design" functionality and integrate it with custom server backend?

Comment: It's not as simple as getting a library - even with a library such as jQuery, I'd think you'd need to hand-code most of it to match your CMS anyway.

Comment: I need a way to design divs within a container and move them around. This is a much slimmer scope I suppose =)

Comment: Ah - I see, that is indeed a more specific question.